# This database URL structure?

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a database site now that has the URL structure:

> example.com/f.php?id=12

I'd like to have

> example.com/f/12

I see this all over the place (IMDb, Wikipedia..) but I can't work out how it's done.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: search for "mod_rewrite" (assuming you are using apache)

Comment: [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called vanity URLS and you can do it with htaccess.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqg6Chk6L7M

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `mod_rewrite`. It is defined in the .htaccess file located at the webroot of your server. Check out this article -> http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Its done using Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). For that example of yours you have to create a .htaccess file in the root folder with the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^f//?(.*)$ f.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

this will present "example.com/f.php?id=12" to "example.com/f/12" and "example.com/f.php?id=12/" to "example.com/f/12/". So it can do with a little teaking. But you get the idea. There are many examples out there, with a minute of googling I came across [this](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/examples.htm).